# Fix nested WordPress multisite resource path?

Tags: multisite

I created multisite subdomain. The root is working great, but, all images and stuff on the subdomain goes to "/sites/2/sites/2/" instead of just "/sites/2/" - How to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution myself.

This is a problem resulting from using a cloning plugin. Manually going into network site settings and updating upload path not to include "/sites/2/" solved it as WordPress appends the path on its own.